# Switch off Memory Leak Detection in boost.Test

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks

I'm currently using boost.Test and I'm wondering if it might be possible to switch off the Memory Leak Detection, if one compiles in DEBUG Mode.

I don't want to use the command line parameter switch `--detect_memory_leak=0`.  I'm looking for a kind of `#define` parameter, that switches off the memory leak detection feature in DEBUG mode.

It would be also suitable for me to switch off the memory detection feature by defining a certain compiler switch. I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK 0 // Preprocesser switch I'm looking for!
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyUnitTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MySuite);

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyUnitTest) {
       /// Following code has a memory leak
       /// ....
    }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe I didn't put my question clear.  The follo#define BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK 0

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe I didn't put my question clear.  It really doesn't matter to me, if I'm compiling in DEBUG or RELEASE mode. I just wanted to know, if there is a macro in boost.Test, that switches of the detection of memory leaks. The above mentioned macro `#define BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK 0` is not working after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly set the environment variable BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK to 0 or use putenv :

```
#include <cstdlib>
//...
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyUnitTest) {
  putenv("BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK=0");
  //...
}
```

**Edit**

As you're using visual studio 2010, you can try [_putenv or _wputenv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zh4e6k(v=vs.100).aspx) :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//...
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyUnitTest) {
  _putenv("BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK=0");
  //...
}
```

Otherwise, I found a function [detect_memory_leaks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/debug/detect_memory_leaks.html) in the Boost documentation but it seems to be only available on recent boost version.

Comment: Good idea! But where should I put the line `putenv("BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK=0");` ? Adding it inside the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` doesn't seem to work for me? As for me I'm working with `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE` only. So there is no `main` function.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks. Using the function `detect_memory_leaks(false)` worked for me. Whereas setting the environment variable with _putenv doesn't seem to had any effect after all.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 7):

Just found out that possibly the best way to turn off the detection of memory leaks is to include the following code snippet into one's tests.

```
#include <boost/test/debug.hpp>

struct GlobalFixture {
    GlobalFixture()   {  
        boost::debug::detect_memory_leaks(false);
    }
    ~GlobalFixture()  {  }
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(GlobalFixture);
```

Still, I was not able to switch off and to switch on the detection of memory leaks for single tests.

Comment: where is the debug namespace locate?

Answer (score 2):

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(0);
```

is the only thing that mostly worked for me. Leak messages came out, but not enough to make me wait.

Here's some code detailing everything I tried:

```
struct GlobalFixture
{
    GlobalFixture()
    {
        // This doesn't seem to do anything
        // boost::debug::detect_memory_leaks(false);

        // This either
        //_putenv("BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK=0");

        // This total hack also does nothing
        // using namespace boost::unit_test::runtime_config;
        // const_cast<boost::runtime::arguments_store&>(argument_store()).set(btrt_detect_mem_leaks, 0);

        // This gets rid of most of the messages
        _CrtSetDbgFlag(0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the _DEBUG macro ?

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define BOOST_TEST_DETECT_MEMORY_LEAK 0
#endif
```